# React native expo cannot resolve font file

Tags: react-native, expo

Im using react native@0.70.5 with expo@~47.0.8
Im trying to use custom fonts and whenever I import them using expo font I get this error: `Unable to resolve "../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.tff" from "core\hooks\useFonts.js"`

here is my react-native.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts/"],
};
```

here's the use font hook

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    "Montserrat-Regular": require("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.tff"),
  });
```

and here's the app.js:

```js
import { View } from "react-native";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

import MainNavigator from "./core/navigation/main";
import useFonts from "./core/hooks/useFonts";

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <MainNavigator></MainNavigator>;
    </View>
  );
}
```

I've tried moving the useFont hook directly to App.js and it still can't resolve the font file. Take note, the path file is absolutely accurate.

edit:
Here is my folder structure

```
ROOT
  App.js
  react-native.config.js
  core
  --hooks
  ----useFonts.js
  assets
  --fonts
  ----Montserrat-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Post your folder structure please

Comment: I've added the folder structure to my question